# From not found where expected

Tags: sql

I am getting the following error "from not found where expected." I use Unix terminal to run this query.it is working correctly in online SQL compiler but showing error in Unix. please help me out.

I have two tables employee and department. I want to find the department name which contains the highest number of employees with dept_id.

My code is:

```
select top 1 dept_name as "result" 
from employee 
join department on employee.dept_id = department.dept_id 
group by dept_name 
order by count (*)
```

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you're running the query in Oracle, yet TOP 1 is SQL Server specific.

Comment: could be you have a space between  count   and  (*)  .. try remove

Comment: You need to give the tables, Either a picture or SQL fiddle or code. This seems very ambiguous.

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc. Looks like Sybase or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dept_name, count(e_id) as Tot from employee e
join department d on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
group by dept_name
order by tot desc
```

Do this in Oracle,
Considering I have no idea about the column names, I am sure there is a column named employee id or 'e_id' in the Employee table. You count that and group by department name.